# Issue with fetch, response.json()

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-native-fetch-blob

I am trying to make an api call using fetch method in react-native.

I have `rn-fetch-blob` for uploading images in one screen which is on another different screen. This particular function was for me to initiate a payment online using paystack. though the issue is not about the paystack because this worked in a new project without having `rn-fetch-blob` in it.
Secondly if i remove `response.json()`,  it wouldn't return anything but there wouldn't be any error. but with response.json(), if get this error
`attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.bridge.readablemap. getstring(java.lang.string)' on a null object reference`.

I suspect there is a conflict between `rn-fetch-blob` and fetch because even without using `rn-fetch-blob`, it runs through perfectly, if i do

```
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.movies;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
```

same error comes

i expect a reference value like hyhjgbhgfh

`attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.bridge.readablemap. getstring(java.lang.string)' on a null object reference`.[image]

I logged out response and i saw [image: _blobInit is blob]

Comment: I don't think the type of 'responseJson' is an object. Why don't you check the type with the console?

Comment: i have done that